# Magento 2 Functional Testing Framework Error!

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I am having trouble installing Functional Testing Framework (FTF) on my Magento 2.

Here is the FTF Guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_introduction.html

But in this step: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_quickstart/mtf_quickstart_environmemt.html

It tells me to enter these on the terminal:

```
cd <magento2>/dev/tests/functional/utils
php generate.php
```

But then it throws an exception error:

```
$ php generate.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid Document
Element 'server': This element is not expected.
Line: 23
' in <mymagento2path>/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:170
Stack trace:
#0 <mymagento2path>/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(129): Magento\Mtf\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Mtf\Util\Iterator\File))
#1 <mymagento2path>/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Config/Data.php(96): Magento\Mtf\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read(NULL)
#2 <mymagento2path>/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Config/Data.php(36): Magento\Mtf\Config\Data->load()
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Mtf\Config\Data->__construct(Object(Magento\Mtf\Config\Reader\Filesystem))
#4 <mymagento2path>/dev/tests/functiona in <mymagento2path>/dev/tests/functional/vendor/magento/mtf/Magento/Mtf/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php on line 170
```

I have no idea what it is talking about! Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your problem, it seems the reason was in the incorrect config.xml file.